# Logging errors From Azure Data Factory in to Application Insights (ADF to ApplicationInsights)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-application-insights

I want to log the errors coming in the azure data factory pipelines into the application insights.
i.e, from ADF in to application insights. is it possible? can someone guide me?

Comment: Is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor) helpful for you?

Comment: I prefer with Application insights. If it doesnt work then I will check Azure monitor. thank you for the reply.

Comment: Did you get the solution to send logs to Application Insights?

Answer (score 1):

I think we can [Using Azure Data Factory with the Application Insights REST API](https://www.ben-morris.com/using-azure-data-factory-with-the-application-insights-rest-api/). It says we could use Web Activity in the ADF to invoke the Application Insights REST API after execution of your main activities(Or using Execute Pipeline Activity to execute your root pipeline and get the status or output of it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But unfortunately, this is to log from Application insights to ADF. I want the other way around.